# Read only a part of a pattern from a file

Tags: bash, shell, grep, pattern-matching

I have a list of strings in a file. I want to find out which of these strings when added to a specific prefix do not exist in another file.

So if the list of strings is like this

```
foo
bar
baz
qux
```

and the target file is this

```
prefix-foo
prefix-barnotreally
prefix-baz
```

the output of the command should be

```
bar
qux
```

I am aware of the `-f` grep flag, but, as far as I know, it doesn't allow the user to use the strings in the file as only a part of the pattern

Comment: Do all of the lines in the target file start with `prefix-`?

Comment: @John Kugelman Yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use process substitution to extract the part of the string from the second file to be passed to the `-f` option of `grep`:

```
grep -vxFf <(cut -f2- -d- file2) file1
```

- `-v` - reverse the search; find lines that don't match
- `-x` - match the whole line
- `-F` - look for strings, not regexes
- `<(cut -f2- -d- file2)` - extract strings from target file, leaving behind the prefix

Comment: This is missing the `-v` flag to grep – the OP is asking for the strings that are _not_ used as suffixes in the second file.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the standard Unix tool `join`:

```
join -t- -1 1 -2 2 -v 1 <(sort file1) <(sort -t- -k 2 file2)
```

The command joins two tables on some join field.  It requires the two files to be sorted by the join field, which is why we need the two sort commands.  We could also make this a bit more readable by using temporary files:

```
sort file1 > file1.sorted
sort -t- -k 2 file2 > file2.sorted
join -t- -1 1 -2 2 -v 1 file1.sorted file2.sorted
```

The first `sort` command simply sorts the lines of the file.  The second sort command sorts by the second field (`-k 2`), using dash as a field separator (`-t-`).

The `join` command also specifies `-` as the field separator (`-t-`), and selects the first column in the first file as join key (`-1 1`), and the second column in the second file (`-2 2`).  The output is restricted to the unpairable rows from the first file (`-v 1`).

If your files are really big, this solution is more efficient than any of the others, but in most practical cases the performance difference shouldn't matter much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk if you are familiar with it. Here is an example:

```
$ cat test.data
prefix-foo
prefix-barnotreally
prefix-baz
$ cat test.awk
BEGIN {
    split("foo bar baz qux", a);
}

/^prefix-*/ {
    gsub("^prefix-", "");
    for (i in a)
        if ($0 == a[i])
            found[$0] = ""
}

END {
    for (i in a)
        if (!(a[i] in found))
            print a[i]
}
$ awk -f test.awk test.data
bar
qux
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bash script that receives as first argument the file containing the strings in that format and as second argument the text file in that format

```
#! /bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <file1> <file2>"
    exit 1
fi

fStrings=$1
file=$2

while read string; do
    cat $file | grep -qw $string
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo $string
    fi
done < $fStrings
```

Answer (score 0):

With awk

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a=a " " $0;next} ! match(a,"\\<"$0"\\>")' targetfile liststrings
```

---

Get all targetfile in a string a and not print the line of liststrings find in string a